# What do you think of saving stack trace in a special log table?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Suppose, you have a special log table of your application.

What do you think about creating a BLOB field for a possible stack trace ?

Logging is done to file as well, but it is not so convenient to read a text file, moreover database is more "accessible".

Comment: What exactly would be the reason for logging the stack trace to a database? What benefit would you get that does not exists when logging to a text file?

Comment: Well generally I will log meaningful messages like "We had an exception while trying do so". But I'm thinking about adding additional field which will hold an exception trace if there was one. Why? Well, more easy to read it. Fast. If you need details, you can delve into full log file.

Comment: Taking into account the limitations of this approach (as summarized by the answers below) I personally would not invest in this feature. There just does not seem to be enough ROI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicate logging sounds like... well, duplicate logging. Overhead. If you need to access the logs through database, I would rather use/write a tool that can import the logs to a separate database when needed. Or make them accessible by some other means. One tool that I know of is Splunk, but it's expensive and I'm sure there are others too.

Comment: I was about to make this very suggestion

Answer (score 4):

What if the stack trace is due to a database connection failure? Some things need to be as low-level and simple as possible. Also, I don't see why a database should be any more or less accessible than a file share or ssh account.

Comment: well it's only a duplicate log, not the main. The main log4j log file will be kept as well.

Answer (score 1):

I previously worked on an application where this happened, but as Marcelo Cantos suggests, it was never really reliable because certain exceptions couldn't be logged there, so we never used it and always relied on log files instead.

If you use the log file to debug errors, you'll also get any other debug of info messages you choose to print, in the correct order; it's rare that all you need is a stack trace, usually what led up to the stack trace is equally if not more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Why ?  Or at least, if you're going to do it, why the Blob field ?

If I were to implement something like this, I would separate the exceptions into separate StackTraceElements and store those into a proper table.  Over time and a variety of failures, you might generate some interesting statistics about the nature of risk and quality within your application.

Comment: @Jim Rush Cause some db engines cannot hold more than 255 chars per char field.

Comment: @EugeneP Correct, I wasn't thinking of it so much as size item, but not having much ability to search the data.  If it were me, I would allow searches by package, class and method.  That combined with statistics from code coverage and testing tools might yield some interesting analytics.